# iOS floating button over table view

Tags: ios, image, button

Is it possible to add a small floating 'settings' button or image-button over a table view? I have buttons on a navigation bar up top, and i dont want to crowd that or remove any

Comment: I'm sure it possible. I would think it makes for a bad UI since it would intercept the touch over the table view.

Comment: Best answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35622509/2269679

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps adding a toolbar with buttons at the bottom would be a better approach?

Comment: Yes, this is the best approach, dont make a bad UI http://iphonesdksnippets.com/post/2009/03/12/Add-toolbar-to-the-bottom.aspx

Comment: I was naively unaware that i could do this, thanks.

Comment: @TeofiloIsraelVizcainoRodrig the link you provided wont work for me as i have a navigation toolbar already.

Comment: It's not a navigation bar, maybe you mean a you have a UITabbar, in that case it would not work

Comment: and in such a case, how would i do that?

Comment: http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/09/navigation-controller-uitoolbar.html

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by adding it to the main window as a subview. Another option and my preferred method: Have a main wrapper view, the table view can be added to that wrapper view as a subview, then add your button as another subview inside of the wrapper view and voila

Comment: This is the answer to the original question :)

Answer (score 0):

To use this method, you should inherit UIViewController and add tableview in it

(1)add button to **self.tableview** in viewDidLoad()

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
[self.tableview addsubview:button];  
[self.tableview bringSubviewToFront:button];
```

(2)set tableview delegate

```
self.tableview.delegate = self;
```

(3) add and update button location to **self.tableview** in scrollViewDidScroll delegate

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
[self.view addSubview:button];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:button];
```

voila~