# Add a disabled from scrolling subview to UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, subview

Is this possible to create a subview in UITableViewController, which will be disabled from scrolling?

http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/9036/map1w.png

Comment: Best answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35622509/2269679

Answer (score 2):

No. You'll want to create a custom view controller, add a UITableView and a fixed view above the UITableView.