# Static footer in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, footer

Im Looking to get my footer to Float over a table view So that it is Always Visible and not only when i scroll to the bottom.

i have tried resizing the table view using this code :

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    if ((self = [super initWithStyle: style]))
    {
        UIView *footer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 45)];
        footer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = footer;
        self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100);
        footer.hidden = NO;

    }
```

I have had no luck thus far.

I have also  tried Using other windows  and resizing all the .XIB files.

Comment: Using this code it will only display when you scroll to the bottom of tableview. if you want t make it visible all the time than create small view and place it below the tableview. that will do it.

Answer (score 15):

A `UITableView`'s `tableFooterView`property is a `UIView`object that is always displayed at the bottom of the content, below the last section. Even if that is not really clear in Apple's documentation (extract : "Returns an accessory view that is displayed **below** the table.").

If you want the footer to be static and non-floating, you have two easy choices :

- Not ideal but simple : Use the last section's footer view as your static footer. This will work at some conditions :

  - your `UITableView` style must be `UITableViewStylePlain` (as `UITableViewStyleGrouped`gives the same behaviour to section headers/footers as to the `UITableView tableHeaderView` and `tableFooterView`
  - You won't be able to use the last section footer for its real purpose : giving footer informations to a specific section

Here is a simple example :

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *view = nil;
    if (section == [tableView numberOfSections] - 1) {
        // This UIView will only be created for the last section of your UITableView
        view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }
    return view;
}
```

- Best solution right now : Add a UIView (either in code or in your XIB) at the same level as your `UITableView`. One little condition :

  - The `self.view` property of your `UIViewController` must not be your `UITableView` object. That means you can't subclass `UITableViewController` but `UIViewController` and make your controller conform to `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols. It's actually simpler than it looks and a better implementation (as far as I'm concerned) than using directly `UITableViewController`.

Here is a simple example in code (but you can do exactly the same using Interface Builder) :

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@end
```

ViewController.m :

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView *tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *fixedTableFooterView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGFloat fixedFooterHeight = 200.0;

    // Initialize the UITableView
    CGRect tableViewFrame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMinY(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds) - fixedFooterHeight);
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableViewFrame style:UITableViewStylePlain]; // or Grouped if you want...
    [self.tableView setDataSource:self];
    [self.tableView setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

    // Initialize your Footer
    CGRect footerFrame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(self.view.bounds) - fixedFooterHeight, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), fixedFooterHeight); // What ever frame you want
    self.fixedTableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:footerFrame];
    [self.fixedTableFooterView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:self.fixedTableFooterView];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    [self setTableView:nil];
    [self setFixedTableFooterView:nil];
}

@end
```

You can also specify `UIViewAutoresizing` mask to make it work seamlessly in portrait and landscape but I didn't to complicate this rather simple code.

**WARNING : This .h and .m files won't compile as I didn't put in the `UITableViewDataSource` required methods. Comment the `setDataSource:` line if you want to see it in action.**

Hope this will help,

Feel free to ask me other details,

Comment: Same as this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687370/tablefooterview-property-doesnt-fix-the-footer-at-the-bottom-of-the-table-view?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can add UIView under the UITableView and it will be always visible.

If you need lot of customisation, just add UITableView to UIViewController instead of using UITableViewController.

Comment: Yes but its possible in case of UIViewController only.
If my view is UITableViewController then ?

Comment: If you need lot of customisation, just add UITableView to UIViewController instead of using UITableViewController

Comment: Yes This seems to be ultimate solution to support all the required features in a seamless manner. Any way thanks dear :)

Comment: there still remains 1 issue in this solution, that I want to use static cells in the table view, which can be used in a UITableView, without using UITableViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will keep your view alway at the bottom of the view:

```
footerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y)
```

Answer (score -3):

A very hacky solution, but this will work :

```
UIWindow *keyWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
[keyWindow.viewForBaselineLayout addSubview:footer];
```

Beware, this will hide everything in your main window that it will overlap.