# How to fix the position of LiquidFloatingActionButton in UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift

I try to fix the position of floating button in the screen but when I scroll the tableView, the button move with cell. Please, any solution let me know.

Comment: My guess is that you're adding the button as a subview of the tableView. You should add the button to the tableView's parent view if possible. If you are using a UITableViewController, this may not be possible though - you'll have to use a UIViewController instead to house the tableview and the floating button.

Comment: Add the button to the view controller's view, not the tableview itself, then it wont move

Comment: I am using UITableViewController.

Comment: You should use View Controller, add button and table over it.

Comment: delete your tableviewcontroller, create new uiviewcontroller and add UITableView as a subview

Comment: @KushalShrestha Add button on view, Not on tableview

Comment: `self.view.addSubview(yourButton)`

Comment: @  iDeveloper , it won't work. maybe  because of UITableViewController

Answer (score 0):

I think you you have actually added the floating button in `UITableViewCell` Mistakenly. Please check It carefully in your ViewController object hierarchy.

Or, if you are using `UITableViewController`, you have To change it to `UIViewController`:

[How to put buttons over UITableView which won't scroll with table in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689805/how-to-put-buttons-over-uitableview-which-wont-scroll-with-table-in-ios)