# Create a floating button over a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, layout

I saw [iOS floating button over table view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605085/ios-floating-button-over-table-view) regarding how to create a floating button. This is the way I create the button. The problem is that the button will scroll with the table view.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(aMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[view addSubview:button];
```

How can I fix that?

I suggest you use https://github.com/gizmoboy7/VCFloatingActionButton this link....hope it will work for you

Comment: Have you subclassed `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController`?

Comment: The easiest way is using MEVFloatingButton library. More information in https://github.com/manuelescrig/MEVFloatingButton

Answer (score 5):

Assign your view controller as the delegate of the table view and override `scrollViewDidScroll:`

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if ([scrollView isEqual:self.tableView]) {
        self.floatingButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y);     
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Austin,

How do I delegate the view controller to the table view.

Thanks

Comment: You would add `self.tableView.delegate = self` to `viewDidLoad`, or connect the delegate outlet in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGPoint origin = [scrollView contentOffset];
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, origin.y)];

    if ([scrollView.panGestureRecognizer translationInView:scrollView].y > 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Now TableView Scrolling UP");
        // Your Custom Code
    } 
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"Now TableView Scrolling Down");
        // Your Custom Code
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope it will helps you..